# Game end in Shark

Tags: scoring, shark

In Shark I think the game ends in one of two ways.  Either one company reaches 15 points, or one pile of counters runs out.  In the first case what happens if a company *would* reach 16 points?  In the second case does the game end immediately after placing the counter, or does it continue until that colour is rolled again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Didn't figure to have to dig my copy of **Shark** out of the garage for this site!

Here are the end of game rules.

> The game is over as soon as
>
> - a company's share price indicator reaches 15,000 on the value scale, or
> - all of the building in a particular colour have been used, or
> - all of the shares have been sold
>
> The bonus that is due in the last round and any share profits or losses need to be resolved.  The players multiply their shares by the current share price and ad their cash to the amount.  The player with the most money has won the game.

**EDIT - Addition**

The game Shark has gone thru a couple revisions.   The original Flying Turtles version has a couple rules differences.

- The big on is the "Rule of 7" - adding to a group of 7 or more does **not** increase the share price.  This will make it much harder to get to 15,000 (you need a minimum of 3 building groups to get there).
- Furthermore, the rules clearly state that 15,000 is the **maximum** share price, so even if you still manage to arrange to shoot to 16,000 or higher, you will be limited to 15,000.

I, (and the folks over on the 'geek) would recommend that you add these rules to your game.